# Qual è il significato di "assurgere" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Andando indietro nel tempo, e scavando nella memoria collettiva: perché gli ultimi *camminanti*, i *camminanti* contemporanei del Massara, nell’estremo tentativo di difendersi e di difendere il loro modo di vita contro l’avanzare del progresso, dell’elettricità, delle strade ferrate e dell’istruzione obbligatoria si erano poi trasformati in delinquenti e banditi: come quel tale soprannominato il *Biundin*, o quell’altro detto il *Moret*, che movimentarono a lungo le cronache della bassa ed **assursero** agli onori della stampa nazionale per conflitti a fuoco tra le risaie e nei pagliai con gli uomini della *Giuvana* (polizia); negli anni stessi, più o meno, che i fratelli Wright compivano i loro primi esperimenti di volo con aeroplani a motore, e che Albert Einstein elaborava la teoria della relatività.

Ho cercato il verbo "assurgere" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che può significare "innalzarsi", "elevarsi", "levarsi in alto". Tuttavia, non riesco a capirne il senso nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In questa frase *assursero* significa proprio *si elevarono*, nel senso che i due malviventi citati, il *Biundin* e il *Moret*, facevano parlare spesso di sé la cronaca locale, e in alcune circostanze particolarmente importanti ne parlava anche la stampa nazionale. In senso ironico questo interesse dei cronisti viene descritto come un alto onore, ben più alto di quello della notorietà locale della bassa. Per questo viene usato il verbo assurgere, che indica un movimento verso l'alto.

Comment: Un dettaglio in più: "assurgere agli onori di" è una 'frase fatta' spesso utilizzata come espressione fissa. Per esempio, Google Books dice che 'assurgere agli' è seguito da 'onori' 2 volte su 3.